# error after inserting few rows in database using java program

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to insert values from one server to another using java program. Here is my code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    Connection conn1 = null;

    ResultSet rs, rs1 = null;

    Statement pst = null;


    try {
        //      dbConnect.executequery(sdate, edate);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@31.4.224.76:1521:RPTPSG", "pihist", "pihist");
        String query = "select * from messagemasterhistory where ROWNUM<=1572660";
        // String query="select * from messagemasterhistory where createdate>='28-JAN-11' and createdate<='18-FEB-2011'";
        pst = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        // String sql="insert into test(SRN ,UTR) values (";
        // pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        // rs.absolute(2000);
        //  pst.setFetchSize(2000);
        //  pst.setMaxRows(1500000);
        pst.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);

        rs = pst.executeQuery(query);

        //  String statment="insert into test(UTR,SRN) values('abc','1')";

        //  PrintWriter wt=new PrintWriter("ritima2.txt");
        conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@31.4.224.81:1521:RPTPSG", "rptr", "rptr");
        Statement stat1 = conn1.createStatement();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String str = rs.getString("FIELDDATA");
            String str1 = rs.getString("FIELDINFO");
            String statment = "insert into MESSAGEMASTERHISTORY2(UTR,CREATEDATE,SENDER,RECEIVER,SUBMESSAGETYPE,FIELDINFO,FIELDDATA,DUPLICATE) values(" + "'" + rs.getString("UTR") + "'" + "," + "TO_DATE('" + rs.getDate("CREATEDATE") + "'" + ",'YYYY-MM-DD\" \"HH24:MI:SS')" + "," + "'" + rs.getString("SENDER") + "'" + "," + "'" + rs.getString("RECEIVER") + "'" + "," + "'" + rs.getString("SUBMESSAGETYPE") + "'" + "," + "'" + str1 + "'" + "," + "'" + str + "'" + "," + rs.getInt("DUPLICATE") + ")";
            // String statment="insert into test1 (fielddata,utr) values("+"'"+(rs.getString("fielddata"))+"'"+","+"'"+rs.getString("UTR")+"')";
            System.out.println(count);
            stat1.executeQuery(statment);

            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println(str1);
            // System.out.println(rs.getClob("FIELDDATA"));
            System.gc();
            count++;
        }
        conn1.commit();
        conn1.close();
        // wt.close();
        System.out.println("Completed");
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
}
```

After inserting few rows (6274) it gives error"java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:963)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at javaapplication2.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Comment: Which line of code is `Main.java:73`?

Comment: The program does not look good. It is ignoring all the best practices in the world. Create the prepared statement with place holders(bind variables), set the values and add that to batch by calling pstmt.addBatch and finally say pstmt.execute().

Answer (score 3):

That's not a very safe way to insert data in a database.
It's vulnerable to SQL injection. Which is probably what's happening.

You probably have a `'` in your inserted data somewhere, which ends the query too soon.

You should check this article out, it'll show you how to use prepared statements, or other ways to protect your query.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

If you're curious you could also look into Hibernate. With a bit of configuration, it can safely persist your entities without having to write lengthy queries yourself

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/

Answer (score 3):

One of the Strings you are copying from the source database probably has an illegal SQL code sequence in it.

You should consider using a PreparedStatement with parameters instead of constructing the SQL using String concatenation.  The PreparedStatement should be pre-compiled, and you don't need to worry about escaping your Strings.

Something like:

```
        String statment = "insert into MESSAGEMASTERHISTORY2(UTR,CREATEDATE,SENDER,RECEIVER,SUBMESSAGETYPE,FIELDINFO,FIELDDATA,DUPLICATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn1.prepareStstement(statement)
        while (rs.next()) {
                    ps.setString(1, rs.getString("UTR"));
                    ps.setDate(2, rs.getDate("CREATEDATE"));
                    // etc etc

                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    conn1.commit(); //maybe you want this outside the loop
        }
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html